# Issues with a simple Chrome Exstension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i am making a very simple exstension, when you click it, it is supposed to open a new tab, and send the user away to www.simplewebstats.com like this:

```
http://simplewebstats.com/process.php?domain="Domain the user is browsing"
```

So if he is browsing google.com, he is supposed to get sendt as

```
http://simplewebstats.com/process.php?domain=google.com
```

Here is what i have

Manifest.json

```
{
   "background_page": "background.html",
   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
   },
   "description": "A free SEO tool for webmasters to track and display web data from most websites. ",
   "name": "SimpleWebStats Site Report",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://www.simplewebstats.com/" ],
   "version": "1.2",
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.html

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

js.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.simplewebstats.com/process.php?ref=plugins&processType=add&domain="+tab.url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1]});
    });
});
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Nothing happens on click

Answer (score 0):

Your define the background.html page in an older version of manifest.json (lower then 1)

The newer version is:

```
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
```

Then again - you can only define a background script (no need for the html):

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```